# Unable to populate data from json to form in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4, tastypie

I have created a form panel and would like to populate json data into form.

I am sending url from tastypie.

```
{"EmailAddress": "aaaaa@gmail.com", "FirstName": "bbbbb", "HomePhone": "23333","resource_uri": "/api/xxxx/1/"}
```

Name of my form panel is formPanel.

When I am trying to run below the data is not populating by showing error.

```
formPanel.getForm().load({
        method : 'GET',
                url : '/api/xxx/1/?format=json',
                });
```

Can any one please help me to load form.

Comment: You need to share actual code to get actual help here, most likely.

Answer (score 2):

@sreekanth, it is possible to load JSON data directly into a form (if the situation really calls for it). Take a look at the docs for [Ext.form.action.Load](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Load). I'm not familiar with the tastypie API, but I suspect that the JSON response may not be exactly what ExtJS expects. From the ExtJS documentation:

> **Response Packet Criteria**
>
> A response packet must contain:
>
> - success property : Boolean
> - data property : Object
>
> The data property contains the values of Fields to load. The
>   individual value object for each Field is passed to the Field's
>   setValue method.

All that said, @sha's suggestion is a good one: Getting familiar with the Store and Model objects in ExtJS will save you time and trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need read about ExtJs concepts for Stores and Models. You don't just load JSON object into ExtJs form. You actually need to create a store, load records to this store and load particular record into form.